# Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket(ConnectAsync) don't refresh host IP (DNS) each time we try to connect

Tags: c#, networking, websocket, uwp, wireshark

i have an UWP application that try to iniiate a websocket connection to a host test.mydomain.com (note that this host don't exist)

```
_websocket = new MessageWebSocket();
_websocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;

_websocket.Closed += _websocket_Closed;
_websocket.MessageReceived += _websocket_MessageReceived;

Uri aoUri = new Uri(url);
                
_websocket.ConnectAsync(aoUri).Completed = (source, status) =>
{
   OnLog("_websocket.Information: " + _websocket.Information);

    if (status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
    {
        messageWriter = new DataWriter(_websocket.OutputStream);
        IsOpen = true;
        OnOpened();
    }
    else if (status == AsyncStatus.Error)
    {
        RaiseError(source.ErrorCode);
        EndConnection();
    }
};
```

When i start the test, i have in my host file

```
1.1.1.1 test.mydomain.com
```

On wireshark side, i can see multiple attempt to connect to host (1.1.1.1 test.mydomain.com)

filter : ip.dst==1.1.1.1 and tcp.port==443

On windows side, if i run ipconfig /display dns all is ok

if i change my host file to

```
2.2.2.2 test.mydomain.com
```

On windows side, if i run ipconfig /display dns, i see the change

On wireshark side,

- i can NOT see attempt to connect to host (2.2.2.2 test.mydomain.com)
  filter : ip.dst==2.2.2.2 and tcp.port==443
- i see that component conninue to invoke  (1.1.1.1 test.mydomain.com)
  filter : ip.dst==1.1.1.1 and tcp.port==443

it seems that the hostname is not resolved each time we try to connect using MessageWebSocket

does anyone know why?

note :

1. that at each connection attempt the object is disposed and recreated
2. if i restart my app, that work and i see attempt to connect to host related to the one setup in my host file
3. if a request Dns.GetHostEntry(aoUri.Host) before trying to connect, Dns.GetHostEntry return the good value compare to messageWebSocket.

Comment: Do you mean the URI that you used for the MessageWebSocket is not changed, you just changed the host file of the server? And what about disconnect and reconnect the MessageWebSocket again, will it try to correct host?

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned `the object is disposed and recreated`, do you mean you've already disposed the `MessageWebSocket` object to clean the cache?